# What was John Buchan's position on Jewish immigration?

Tags: jews, canada, immigration

Canada was very restrictive about Jewish immigration in the late 1930's.  John Buchan was governor general of Canada at that time.  What was his position on Jewish immigration into Canada at that time?

Comment: Have you done any preliminary research? What does Wikipedia show about Buchan or about Canadian immigration policy?  What was the role of the Governor General in policy formulation?  You might want to consult [Help] ; questions that demonstrate preliminary research tend to get more interest, and ultimately more answers.

Answer (score 4):

A quick google search led me to [Model Prime Minister](https://books.google.com/books?id=FTsz_YSg8FYC&lpg=PT180&ots=VHJyaSPyAw&dq=John%20Buchan%20jewish%20immigration&pg=PT180#v=onepage&q=John%20Buchan%20jewish%20immigration&f=false) which states that Buchan's name was entered in the Golden Book as a friend of the Jews, but that he was unable to overcome his government's "tragically intransigent policy that excluded Jewish immigration".